# Browser freeze when I load tinyMCE via jQuery .load()

Tags: php, jquery, tinymce

I run into a problem, struggling for hours. I am using jQuery load to load a php page which contains tinyMCE and its scripts (wordpress)

```
    $('.quickedit_form_' + parentID).load('<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/ajax/quickedit.php?id=' + parent.attr('id').replace('post-', ''), function(){
        tinyMCE.init({ 
            skin: 'wp_theme'
        });
        $.scrollTo(parent, 800, {offset: {left: 0, top: -61}});
    });
```

And my php page (quickedit.php)

```
<?php

// include WordPress
require('../../../../wp-blog-header.php');

// get post
global $current_user;
$id = $_GET['id'];
$post = get_post($id);
if ($current_user->ID != $post->post_author) {
    wp_die(__('Unauthorized access.','sofa'));
}

?>

<h1 class="quickedit_h"><?php printf(__('Editing Post #%s','sofa'), $post->ID); ?></h1>

<label for="edit_title_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="quickedit_label"><?php _e('Title:','sofa'); ?></label>
<input type="text" name="edit_title_<?php echo $id; ?>" id="edit_title_<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?php echo $post->post_title; ?>" class="quickedit_field" />

<label for="edit_type_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="quickedit_label"><?php _e('Post Type:','sofa'); ?></label>
<select name="edit_type_<?php echo $id; ?>" id="edit_type_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="quickedit_select">
    <option value="text"<?php selected("text", sofa_post_type()); ?>><?php _e('Blog','sofa'); ?></option>
    <option value="image"<?php selected("image", sofa_post_type()); ?>><?php _e('Image','sofa'); ?></option>
    <option value="video"<?php selected("video", sofa_post_type()); ?>><?php _e('Video','sofa'); ?></option>
</select>

<div class="quickedit_save"><input type="button" value="<?php _e('Save','sofa'); ?>" class="button-secondary" /></div>

<?php
wp_editor( $post->post_content, 'edit_content_'.$id, $settings =  array(
    'wpautop' => true,
    'media_buttons' => true,
    'textarea_name' => 'edit_content_'.$id,
    'textarea_rows' => 10,
    'tabindex' => '',
    'editor_css' => '',
    'editor_class' => 'edit_content',
    'teeny' => false,
    'dfw' => false,
    'tinymce' => true,
    'quicktags' => true
));
?>

<div class="quickedit_save"><input type="button" value="<?php _e('Save','sofa'); ?>" class="button-secondary" /></div>

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

When I access quickload.php directly in browser, everything load smooth, no delay or anything. But when I access it via jQuery .load() the tinymce and buttons take about 15 seconds to load, freezing browser (user can't interact with anything) tried in both Firefox and chrome.

Can anyone suggest to me why this is happening, been hours trying with this.. :(

**Note: when i access quickedit.php directly the tinymce loads fine and quick. the crash/freezing happens when its called from jquery .load function.**

I need any directions to what could be causing this problem?

Comment: I am having the same issue with .get()  Through my debugger it is freezing while loading the jquery.min.ui.js file for me - nothing to do with asynch.  It only freezes/slow to load on the first .get() request on the page, any subsequent requests respond as expected. I am thinking it is something to do with the proxy server for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using jQuery's low level ajax interface: jQuery.ajax

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var ajax_url = '<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/ajax/quickedit.php?id=' + parent.attr('id').replace('post-', ''); //Included for readability
  //Check if the elem is in the DOM, if so, load it via AJAX
  if ($('.quickedit_form_' + parentID).length >0) {
    $.ajax({ 
       url: ajax_url
       complete: function  () {
          tinyMCE.init({ 
          skin: 'wp_theme'
          });
         $.scrollTo(parent, 800, {offset: {left: 0, top: -61}});
       }
    });
  }
});
```

The reason you may be running into errors is do to the multiple argument nature of jQuery.load (plus I think its deprecated...?) may be causing a synchronous (blocking) request.